# BS4 Reduce Padding Between 2-Up Grid Cards on Mobile

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap-4 page grid cards. On mobile devices (col), I would like them to display 2 up, but I get twice the padding between the cards than I do on the outside. This is the result of the left and right card padding meeting in between the two cards.

Because the number of cards can vary from 1 to 99 I am not sure how to reduce the inner padding to even things out. See image: Green is left and right padding. Gray is the card area.

[image: diagram of grid cards and padding. gray is the card and green is the padding]

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code

Comment: Please check my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61258367/2719317.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css to your card element that has padding, it will remove the padding left only for the right side card and will gives you back same padding from all sides

replace this text with your card class that has padding "your-card-padded-class"

```
your-card-padded-class:nth-child(even) {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Slight expansion of your solution worked. I needed to reduce the inner padding of the even and odd children by half and only on mobile.

 @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
    .product-cards .col {
      &:nth-child(even) {
        padding-left: 7px;
      }

      &:nth-child(odd) {
        padding-right: 7px;
      }
    }
  }

Your solution makes the cards different widths.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is repeating two times because all `col-*` are having

```
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
```

You can overwrite is by adding `padding: 0`.

**EXAMPLE**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-4 p-0">I am first</div>
  <div class="col-4 p-0">I am second</div>
  <div class="col-4 p-0">I am third</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution removes all padding. I needed to reduce the inner padding by 1/2 to balance the inner and outer padding on mobile devices